# Is there any decent Wordpress blogging client for Mac?

Tags: macos, wordpress

On Windows I used to blog to Wordpress using Microsoft Word 2010 blog feature, but the Mac version is missing this feature.

I am looking for alternatives, preferably free ones. If you specify a commercial solution please include the price:  `name (x$)`.

Please do not suggest generic text/html editors and submit different suggestions as separated answers.

Comment: I am a Mac User since Tiger and a casual blogger as well. I have Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro right now, and reason for having Windows is 1 software, it's call'ed Windows Live Writer. It's awesome if you are blogging. If Microsoft ports Windows Live Writer to Mac OS X in future, I'll remove Windows at that moment only ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have basically two choices, both payware:

### [Marsedit](http://www.red-sweater.com/marsedit/)

$39.95: "The best way to write, preview, and publish your blog."

and

### [Ecto](http://illuminex.com/ecto/)

$19.95: "ecto is a feature-rich desktop blogging editor for MacOSX"

Both programs offer trial versions.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider [Flock](http://www.flock.com/), a free, Firefox-based browser with many other features, including a built in [blog editor](http://www.flock.com/user-guide/2.6/advblog.html). It's quite an unusual program, as you can also use it to manage your Facebook and Twitter accounts and feeds. It's worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not willing to drop Chrome :D

Comment: Also worth noting that Flock development has just been [discontinued](http://www.macworld.com/article/159186/2011/04/flock_discontinued.html), as of yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the best solutions (ecto and MarsEdit) are not free. There is [one alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/ecto/?platform=mac), but I would rather promote Sorin's solution of using Flock. If you are a TextMate, you can also use the XMLRPC capabilities of its Blogging bundle to blog from there.

Just curious, what more does a standalone editor offer in comparison to the WordPress rich text editor? I blog in plain text/html, but I think I remember the WordPress rich text environment to be rather flexible, with great media support for instance, as long as you are using a browser like Firefox.

Comment: I preferred using MarsEdit when my blogs were on MovableType (an old version at that), but now that they are on WordPress, I just use the built-in WP editor.

Comment: Of course, Flock has been discontinued, unfortunately. I don't remember whether [RockMeIt](http://www.rockmelt.com/) does blogging, and their site is particularly unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

[Bits](http://bitsapp.info) - diary app with photos, tags, cloud sync and wordpress integration.

[image: Bits screenshot]

Comment: If you want to add additional value to your answer, please include additional information about the application. Of special interest are features which make ths app standout from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You should also look at [Blogo](http://www.drinkbrainjuice.com/blogo)

> Publish text, images, videos,
>   slideshows and more. With a simple,
>   intuitive interface and support for
>   Wordpress, Blogger, Typepad, Typo,
>   Drupal, Joomla, and Expression Engine,
>   Blogo is the best way to maintain your
>   blog and spread the word with Twitter,
>   Ping.fm and other supported services.

for $25. I have used it before, and it was pretty good. They have a trial period, so you can check them out.

Answer (score 0):

> #### [Byword](http://bywordapp.com/)
>
> *Publish to **WordPress**, Tumblr, Blogger, Scriptogram blogs and Evernote notebooks directly from Byword. Requires a one-time in-app purchase.*

Price: $10. **OSX and iOS**. No trial, only available at Apple App Stores. Supports Markdown, not sure about HTML.

---

> #### [MacJournal](http://www.marinersoftware.com/products/macjournal/)
>
> *You can keep your world private or, like so many do, share your thoughts and opinions or your entire life. Your MacJournal entries can be published to any of the popular blogging services like Blogger, **WordPress**, LiveJournal, Tumblr and more.*

Price: $40. OSX only. Has a trial version. Tested in my localhost server and works ok. Can create new posts, or download all existing posts and edit/update them. Doesn't seem to support HTML.

---

> #### [myWPEdit](http://mywpedit.com/)
>
> *myWPEdit is an easy-to-use weblog editor focusing on the most important functions for blogger with easy to use features and a clean user interface. Why should you hinder yourself by using the slow and hard-to-use web interface WordPress comes with, if you could do it with style and comfort of a real Mac application.*

Price: $10. OSX only. No trial, only available at Apple App Store. Supports Markdown and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

SmartXBlog is desktop blog editor for both windows and mac , it has WYSIWYG editor, image editor, online news, image and video search, drag and drop option, bookmarks , rss feed available from nearly 100 popular websites and you can even add your own rss, pop up alerts of your comments and you can preview and publish your post directly to your wordpress account .I think it is best available blogging desktop editor for windows and mac.

[image: SmartXBlog Editor]

Free trial can be downloaded from

http://www.smartxblog.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [WordMark](http://wordmarkapp.com). Way cheaper than MarsEdit. It supports multiple platforms such as Wordpress, Medium, Tumblr, Blogger.... also supports Markdown if you are a fan.