# Is there a free wordpress client for mac?

Tags: wordpress, macos

I am a new Mac user and a casual blogger. All the applications listed are expensive, as I am a student. I am scared to set up Wordpress natively on my MacBook Air. Something like the wordpress app on android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any decent Wordpress blogging client for Mac?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10073/is-there-any-decent-wordpress-blogging-client-for-mac)

Answer (score 1):

If you are a casual blogger then your best bet is to use the web client built into your Wordpress installation, just log in to your blog and away you go.

And I believe that the Wordpress app for IOS is free...

Answer (score 1):

Most WordPress agencies use three local desktop clients to build WordPress on their MacBook.

Local By Flywheel: https://localwp.com/

ServerPress: https://serverpress.com/

Mamp: https://www.mamp.info/

All of these offer an easy install and set up with a few clicks. If you install a lot of sites on your desktop client, you'll load up your MacBook storage. Images and files have to live somewhere on your computer.

I would recommend using these to anyone wanting to learn WordPress, maybe development, and not have to spend a dime in the process.

I use Local By Flywheel and my host is with WPEngine.com. The WP Engine Connect feature allows me to connect any of my sites on my WP Engine Account and download associated environments. It's pretty cool.

https://wpengine.com/support/local/

Comment: Nice balanced recommendation. Great first post. Welcome to Ask Different.